# reinitialise transactional replication without dropping subscriber table 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Normally when we reinitialise transactional replication it drops the table on the subscriber and recreates it.  I want to have a clustered PK on the source database with a non-clustered PK of the same column on the destination and a different clustered index.  I understand I can achieve this by temporarily stopping the replication making the changes and enabling it again.

I'm more worried about the future if we ever need to reinitialise I don't want the table to be dropped and lose our different index strategy.  I might be being blind but I can't find a setting to allow the table structure on the subscriber to be kept on reinitialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  You set this in the article properties of the replication.  You can choose to truncate all data if the table already exists.